# Reading txt File

Tags: python, list, numpy, text

I'm trying to read a .txt file and extract the floats to a list. The txt file constists of 3 and sometimes 2 columns since the (mm) is missing

I only want to extract the numer at the end of the line and put it into a list

```
 SHAPE\SEC_1\WIDTH_UPR_01 (mm)  40
 SHAPE\SEC_1\HIGHT_01 (mm)  35
 SHAPE\SEC_1\WIDTH_LWR_01 (mm)  40
 SHAPE\SEC_1\NEUTRAL_WEB_SHIFT_01   0.7
 SHAPE\SEC_1\NEUTRAL_WEB_WIDTH_01 (mm)  30
```

i tried it with a numpy function called np.load

```py
import numpy as np


x= np.loadtxt("CATIA_DV_File.txt", dtype='string',  delimiter=' ', unpack=True)
```

Comment: Did you miss the part of your code out where you're trying to extract the floats into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("CATIA_DV_File.txt") as fh:
    data = [line.split()[-1] for line in fh]
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float64)
```

this will read the file line by line, grab the last "word" on each line and put it in a list, then it will convert the list into a numpy array with a float type
this can be condensed into a one liner:

```
data = np.array([line.split()[-1] for line in open("CATIA_DV_File.txt")], dtype=np.float64)
```

Comment: `data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float64)` it overwrites the data, you will have only the last line??

Comment: that line is not in the loop, it runs AFTER the loop turning the list we generated into an array

Comment: Works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Read the file normally, split each line and then append the last element in the split to a list.

```
float_list = []

with open("CATIA_DV_File.txt","r") as f:
  for line in f:
    float_list.append(float(line.split()[-1]))

print(float_list)
```